# Send POST request via native Web Browser

Tags: android

Is it possible to send POST request to specified url via Android native Web Browser using startActivity for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done , it however would allow you to do a simple Get request.but not a post request.You may have to try it doing programmatically or try some plugin like the 'POSTMAN' for chrome,something like that for android.

Comment: Do u know maybe then how to send GET with params?